# Avoiding figure display top of first column with ieeeconf

Tags: floats, ieeeconf

I am writing a paper with the `IEEEconf` template using texmaker/miktex in windows. When including the first figure :

```
\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{./figures/figure}
\caption{figure cap}
\label{label}
\end{figure}
```

I end up with the figure occupying the space before the abstract, at the very beginning of the paper, which is neither pretty, nor acceptable. I tried to look up for solving that issue on the internet, because I thought is must be very common and did not find anything.

How should I deal with this ? Are there any options that I can stack to \begin{figure} ?

Comment: most implementations of `\maketitle` prevent figures at the top of the title page but you could use `\usepackage{flafter}` to force figures never to float backwards

Comment: oh you have used `!` which says to ignore the constraints, so even if the class specifies no top floats on the first page you have over-ridden that. Don't add `!` to the option except in _very_ special circumstances.

Comment: I tried `\usepackage{flafter}` but without removing `!`, it worked anyways

Comment: yes they work in different ways, flafter changes the float algorithm so floats never move top the top of the page where they are specified. `!` in an option says to ignore the numeric constraints,  It is almost always wrong to use `!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most implementations of \maketitle prevent figures at the top of the title page.

however you have used `!` which says to ignore the constraints, so even if the class specifies no top floats on the first page you have over-ridden that. Don't add `!` to the option except in very special circumstances.

Alternatively  you could use `\usepackage{flafter}` to force figures never to float backwards.